# 3 category car insurance probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I couldn't find any 3 category car insurance examples. I was able to deduce part a but I could use some help trying to figure out part b) of the following:

An insurance company believes that people can be classified into three groups: good risk,
average risk or bad risk. Their statistics show that the probabilities of good, average and bad
risk individuals being involved in an accident in any one year are $0.04$, $0.12$ and $0.3$ respectively.
Assume that $20$% of the population can be classified as good risk, $55$% as average risk and $25$% as
bad risk.

> a. Find the proportion of policy holders having accidents in any one year.

> b. Suppose that a new policy holder has an accident within a year of purchasing a policy. Find
> the probability that the policy holder is an average risk.

For part a, I think it was just asking for the total probability of an accident which was P(A) = P(good)P(A|good) + P(avg)P(A|avg) + P(bad)P(A|bad), which is: $$.2(.04)+.55(.12)+.25(.3) = .149.$$

I think part b) involves Bayes' theorem where P(avg|A) = (P(A|avg)P(avg))/P(A), and where the denominator is the answer from part a, and the numerator are given parts from the statement.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This is not a problem about car insurance. This is a probability problem which involves Bayes' theorem in part b. This is also a *word problem*, which means it also requires you to translate it from "real life" to the language of mathematics. As you said you were able to do part a, can you show us how far you've got, which will be helpful to decide at which level to write the answer for the part b.

Comment: Sure for part a, I think it was just asking for the total probability of an accident which was P(A) = P(good)P(A|good) + P(avg)P(A|avg) + P(bad)P(A|bad)

Comment: which is .2(.04)+.55(.12)+.25(.3) which is .149 I think part b involves Bayes' theorem where P(avg|A) which is (P(A|avg)P(avg))/P(A) where the denominator is the answer from part a, and the numerator are given parts from the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20% is $0.2$. Since the probability of any of them getting an accident is $0.04$, the total amount out of the total population is $0.2\cdot 0.04 = 0.008.$

Similarly, $0.12\cdot 0.55=0.066$ and $0.3\cdot 0.25 = 0.075$ are the probabilities for average and bad risk people getting an accident in one year.

$$0.008+0.066+0.075 = 0.149.$$

This means $$\boxed{14.9\%}$$
had accidents in one year.

The average people contribute $6.6\%$, so $\frac{6.6\%}{14.9\%} \approx 0.4429.$

Therefore, for b the answer is $$\boxed{44.29\%}$$

Comment: Thank you, you're a beast!